# Changing of a words gender depending on usage?

Tags: usage, gender

In the sentence

> Auf der Bühne steht ein großer Käfig

Bühne appears masculine, despite it being a feminine word.
Is the gender correlating to the object of the sentence (Kafig)? Why does this happen and when do I do it?

Comment: Artikel not only change by noun gender but also by case and number. The dative case definite article for feminine nouns is *der*. https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/nouns-and-articles/articles-noun-markers

Comment: It may appear masculine to beginners if they look exclusively at 'der Bühne'. After all, it resembles 'der Hühne', who is definitely masculine. But as soon as they look at 'auf der Bühne' they recollect that a case change happens after the preposition 'auf' - either to accusative (with motion) or to dative (with state).

Comment: @BenA. It's "Hüne".

Comment: @Uwe You're right. Shame on me. At least, there is a resemblance as to the pronunciation.